# Existence of the thermodynamic limit of the hamiltonian operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, many-body

Given a N-particle system, with Hamiltonian operator equal to ${H}_N$. I'm interested in studying the limit N to infinity of the average of the hamiltonian over a set of states $\psi_{N}$. Is it necessary to have a constant $C$ such that the average of the hamiltonian over the state $\psi_{N} $ is bounded by $C N$ to say that the limit is well defined ? Equivalently, is it necessary to say that the energy per particle is bounded to have a good limit? I'm not sure if there are physical systems where this is not true but, nevertheless, it is still a well defined quantum system.

Finally, is it always true that the energy of a system increases linearly with the total number of particles composing the system?

Comment: Why do you think the energy (I suppose you mean ground state energy? or do you mean all expectation values?) increases linearly with $N$? Take e.g. two non-interacting (for the sake of simplicity spinless) identical fermions; let the single-particle energies be $\epsilon_n:=n^2$; then for $N=1$, the ground state energy is $\epsilon_1=1$, for $N=2$, the ground state energy is $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2=5$.

Comment: You might want to look up "stability of matter in quantum mechanics" or so, to start with. I think the existence of the TDL (in qm) is a non-trivial business.

Comment: @TobiasFünke your example does not apply to the question, with $N=2$, you are far from the thermodynamic limit. On the contrary, letting $N\to\infty$, you recover an extensive ground state energy confirming MBlrd’s hunch.

Comment: @LPZ For $N$ particles, the ground state energy is $E(N)=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$ in my example. I don't see why this should be a linear function; the limit $N\to \infty$ does not even exist. I think there are some details missing here...

Comment: @TobiasFünke Your approach is not physical. I think that what you had in mind is a 1D fermion gas. Physically, the size of the box is extensive as well $L\propto N$ to have an intensive particle density. The energy levels are therefore rather spaced as $(n/N)^2$ and you do get an extensive mean energy.

Comment: The trick is to find the correct scaling of the various parameters of the Hamiltonian to get a well defined TDL, which is why it is hard to justify in general.

Comment: @LPZ Yes, I forgot to add that in my last comment: It is a made up example, to invalidate the claim in the question, which I did not read in the context of the TDL. Anyway: Yes, I agree with your last comments.